# How to configure the zoom level in the Map?

Tags: blackberry, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades, momentics

I'm developing a BlackBerry 10 mobile application using the Momentics IDE (native SDK).

I want to display a map using the mapview qml element which seems that it belongs to the blackberry team (it's not a google map). [[ Blackberry 10 mapview ]](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__maps__mapview.html)

All I want is to configure the zoom level like google do, but it looks like the blackberry map doesn't have any attribute which can guarantee that except the "altitude" element which can assign some sort of zoom .

Any one can help on this ?

Answer (score 1):

The altitude property is indeed the one you use for zooming. The paradigm is "how much area is viewable from a given altitude?"

Answer (score 0):

To zoom in and zoom out from the map uses the `altitude` property.
To create zoom in/out animation you can use a simple javascript function that manages the animation. (For example implementing Elastic or Circular animation. See the Blackberry Stock Curves documentation for more details).
Instead, if you want determinate the viewable area from a given altitude you should work with the map scale
[http://www.geog.ucsb.edu/~jeff/115a/lectures/scale_and_area_measurement.html](http://www.geog.ucsb.edu/%7Ejeff/115a/lectures/scale_and_area_measurement.html)

regards